# Where can I find detailed historical breakdowns of U.S. lightning fatalities on a year-by-year basis?

Tags: meteorology, statistics, lightning

e.g. Something like [this](http://www.lightningsafety.noaa.gov/fatalities/fatalities17.shtml), but for historical years (preferably covering 1980-2007, since the NWS detailed lists only start from 2008). Location of strike, victim name, where the victim was at (under tree, out on open water, at beach), etc.

If such a resource does not exist, then what's the next best thing? All the archived meteoroepidemiology (yes I know that's not a word) data I've been able to find is limited to overall numbers of lightning deaths by state/on a national basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a comprehensive literature review of sources of lightning fatalities data you can check the paper "[Striking Back: An Assessment of Lightning related Fatality and Injury Risk in Canada](http://lsg.biology.ualberta.ca/facilities/safety/uploads/PDF/Lightning-relatedinjuriesandfatalitiesinCanada_FINAL-TECHNICAL_1-September-06.pdf)", it covers US and Canadian sources. But if you want to know which one is the largest and arguably the best. That would be [NOAA's Storm Database](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/stormevents/). The data you can access trough the online interface is quite limited, so I would recommend to go to the [Bulk Data Download](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/stormevents/ftp.jsp) area, and get the original spreadsheets. You will see 3 files per year: Locations, Fatalities and Details, from 1950 to 2017. I would recommend to download the "Details" files, as it also have information about the location (Lat/Lon) and number of deaths and injuries, and a short narrative of the event.
It is a large table, as an example, I took the following screenshot of the most important data columns for all the lightning events with casualties in 2009:

[image]

You can download the Fatalities file if you want more info abut the age, gender and location of the victim. The relevant fields look like this:

[image]